# How to bring my tables in sql workbench?

Tags: database, h2

I am trying to see the tables I've made in my project with h2 in the sql workbench, but after connecting to my database I only see this snapshot:
[image]

how can I see and access the contents of my database?

Comment: if any thing in my question is vague, please ask it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables can be show by using `show tables`

You can write queries by going to `view > statement`.